# Download repository from Github

Tags: yeoman

I'm trying to learn Yeoman, but find the official documentation severely lacking. I've found the `remote()` function which appears to download a GIT repository but whatever I do I can't get it to work without throwing errors.

Here's what I have:

```
this.remote('powerbuoy', 'SleekWP', 'master', function (err, remote) {
    if (err) {
        this.log(err);

        return err;
    }

    remote.copy('.', this.destinationPath('wp-content/themes/sleek/'));
}.bind(this));
```

What I'm hoping would happen here is that the https://github.com/powerbuoy/SleekWP/ repo is downloaded and moved to wp-content/themes/sleek/. What happens instead is I get:

```
fs.js:603
  var r = binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                  ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Is there a better documentation or a tutorial explaining all these basics somewhere? I'd love to know how to copy files without each copy being printed to the console too for example. This all seems pretty basic but http://yeoman.io/authoring/ is very sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the solution was to use `remote.bulkDirectory()` instead of `remote.copy()`.

Edit: However, reading the "documentation" (can barely be called that) it says that "You should never use this method, unless there's no other solution." (http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_actions.html)

So if anyone knows of the proper way to do this I'd love to know.

I switched to the fs-extra package and used `cacheRoot()` and `destinationRoot()` to copy the directory instead:

```
fs.copy(this.cacheRoot() + '/username/Project/branch/', this.destinationPath('destination/path/')
```